Looking for suggestions and advice for setting relaxation method in knapsack branch and bound algorithm
I have an assignment to solve a Knapsack problem from a set of datasets I'm given.  One of the ways I have to solve it is with a branch and bound depth-first algorithm. The program below works fine when given a dataset with a capacity of 100000 and the number of items of 30, but when that increases to 341045 capacity and the number of items of 50, the program gives me an error memory allocation failed not enough space. The problem, from what I've gathered, is that the optimistic value is too relaxed, and not enough nodes get pruned.  If I set the optimistic value myself (up to 2000000, I believe, but I could be wrong), the program runs fine and gives a result, but it's not accurate enough. Any method or suggestions to set the optimistic value so the program can run for different datasets by itself without manually setting a "acceptable" optimistic value would be appreciated.
I also know I can try different methods, such as greedy algorithm or dynamic programming, but the assignment specifically wants branch and bound.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    int weight;
    int value;
} Item;
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    int weight;
    int estimate;
    int level;
    int* selected; //pointer toy selected
} Node;
typedef struct QueueNode {
    Node data;
    struct QueueNode* next;
} QueueNode;

typedef struct {
    QueueNode* front;
    QueueNode* rear;
} Queue;

// Function to create a new queue
Queue* createQueue() {
    Queue* queue = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    if (queue == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    return queue;
}

Node createNode(int value, int weight, int estimate, int level, int* selected, int length) {
    Node newNode;
    newNode.value = value;
    newNode.weight = weight;
    newNode.estimate = estimate;
    newNode.level = level;
    newNode.selected = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory for the selected array
    if (newNode.selected == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        newNode.selected[i] = selected[i];
    }
    return newNode;
} 

//Function to check if the queue is empty
int isEmpty(Queue* queue) {
    return queue->front == NULL;
}

// Function to enqueue a node
void enqueue(Queue* queue, Node newNode) {
    QueueNode* newNodePtr = (QueueNode*)malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
    if (newNodePtr == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newNodePtr->data = newNode;
    newNodePtr->next = NULL;

    if (queue->rear == NULL) {
        queue->front = queue->rear = newNodePtr;
        return;
    }

    queue->rear->next = newNodePtr;
    queue->rear = newNodePtr;
}

// Function to dequeue a node
Node dequeue(Queue* queue) {
    if (isEmpty(queue)) {
        perror("Queue is empty");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    QueueNode* temp = queue->front;
    Node data = temp->data;
    queue->front = queue->front->next;

    if (queue->front == NULL)
        queue->rear = NULL;

    free(temp);
    return data;
}

// Function to free the memory occupied by the queue
void freeQueue(Queue* queue) {
    while (!isEmpty(queue)) {
        dequeue(queue);
    }
    free(queue);
}
int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char filename[] = "pr2_50"; //ONOMA FILE
    int K, N;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    start = clock();

    // Open file
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d %d", &K, &N); //K=Knapsack Capacity, N=Number of items
    
    // Allocate memory for items
    Item *items = (Item *)malloc(N * sizeof(Item));
    if (items == NULL) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    int optimistic_value=0;
    // Read items from file
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (fscanf(file, "%d %d", &items[i].weight, &items[i].value) != 2) {
            perror("Error reading file");
            fclose(file);
            return 1;
        }
        optimistic_value=optimistic_value+items[i].value;
    }
    fclose(file);
    int level=0;
    int max = 0;
    int maxw=0;
    Queue* queue = createQueue();
    int current_value=0;
    int current_weight=0;
    int selection[N];
    int finalselection[N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        selection[i] = 0;
        finalselection[i] = 0;
    }
    Node newNode = createNode(current_value, current_weight, optimistic_value, level, selection, N);
    enqueue(queue, newNode);
    while(!isEmpty(queue))
    {
      Node currentNode = dequeue(queue);
      level = currentNode.level+1;
      if (level<=N){
        current_weight = currentNode.weight;
        current_value = currentNode.value;
        optimistic_value = currentNode.estimate;
        int *selection = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if (selection == NULL) {
            perror("Memory allocation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++) {
            selection[i] = currentNode.selected[i];
        }
        if(current_weight+items[level-1].weight<=K && optimistic_value>max)
        {
            selection[level-1]=1;
            Node additem = createNode(current_value+items[level-1].value, current_weight+items[level-1].weight, optimistic_value, level,  selection, N);
            enqueue(queue, additem);
            if (max<additem.value){
                max=additem.value;
                maxw=additem.weight;
                for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
                    finalselection[i]=selection[i];
                }

            }
        }
        if(optimistic_value>max)
        {
            selection[level-1]=0;
            Node noitem = createNode(current_value, current_weight, optimistic_value-items[level-1].value, level,  selection, N);
            enqueue(queue, noitem);
        }
        free(selection);
      }
      else{
        freeQueue(queue);
        K=K-maxw;
        printf("Selected items:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (finalselection[i]==1) {
                printf("Item %d: Weight = %d, Value = %d\n", i+1, items[i].weight, items[i].value);
            }
        }
        free(items);
        break;
      }
      free(currentNode.selected);
    }
    printf("Total value in knapsack is %d \n ", max);
    printf("Backpack capacity: %d\n", K);
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000; // Convert to milliseconds
    printf("Program executed in %.2f milliseconds.\n", cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}

